# formulas xml to csv file conversion

Tags: xml, parsing, csv

Need help to add formula in php file and convert to csv file from xml data.

Here is my construction data:

XML File:

```
<PRODUCTS>
<PRODUCT code="012345" price="100"/>
<PRODUCT code="123456" price="200"/>
<PRODUCT code="123457" price="300"/>
<PRODUCTS/>
```

Here is the PHP File:

```
<?php
    $filexml = 'price.xml';
    if (file_exists($filexml))
    {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
        $file = fopen('price.csv', 'w');

        $header = array('code', 'price');
        fputcsv($file, $header, ',', '"');

        /** @var SimpleXMLElement $product */
        foreach ($xml->PRODUCT as $product)
        {
        $value1 = $product->attributes()->code;
        $value2 = $product->attributes()->price;
        $formula = $value2 * 0.95;
            fputcsv($file, $value1, $formula, ',', '"');
        }

        fclose($file);

    }
?>
```

The result need to be:

CSV File:

```
code,price
012345,95
123456,190
123457,285
```

The problem is that my script is returning only the header.
I will appreciate if anyone can help me to correct the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
foreach ($xml->PRODUCTS->PRODUCT as $product)
```

?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast response, i have resolved the issue with $items = array();